# Multiple input split into groups

Tags: php, cakephp

So I have this form to add a Report, and my Report hasMany Measures. My problem is, I want to "split" the display of the Measures into groups (a Measure belongsTo a Group).

I have this:

```
//Controller/Report/add

$measures = $this->Report->Measure->find('list');
```

and this:

```
//View/Report/add.ctp

echo $this->Form->input('Measure', array('label' => false, 'multiple' => 'checkbox'));
```

This outputs:

```
<div class="input select">
    <input type="hidden" name="data[Measure][Measure]" value="" id="MeasureMeasure"/>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="data[Measure][Measure][]" value="1" id="MeasureMeasure1" />
        <label for="MeasureMeasure1">
            ...
        </label>
    </div>

      ....
</div>
```

However I need something like:

```
<h2>Measure Group 1</h2>
    <div class="input select">
        <input type="hidden" name="data[Measure][Measure]" value="" id="MeasureMeasure"/>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="data[Measure][Measure][]" value="1" id="MeasureMeasure1" />
            <label for="MeasureMeasure1">
                ...
            </label>
        </div>

          ....
    </div>
<h2>Measure Group 2</h2>
    <div class="input select">
        <input type="hidden" name="data[Measure][Measure]" value="" id="MeasureMeasure"/>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="data[Measure][Measure][]" value="1" id="MeasureMeasure1" />
            <label for="MeasureMeasure1">
                ...
            </label>
        </div>

          ....
    </div>
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will take a bit of extra work to prepopulate the fields for editing when setting the request data to the view but you could do something like this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Measure.Measure.group1', array('options'=>$options, 'label' => false, 'multiple' => 'checkbox'));
echo $this->Form->input('Measure.Measure.group2', array('options'=>$options, 'label' => false, 'multiple' => 'checkbox'));
```

Should give you something in your controller like this:

```
pr($this->data['Measure']['Measure']['group1']);

array(
   [0] => someval,
   [1] => some other val
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I solved it, basically I did:

```
$this->loadModel('Measuregroup');
$this->Measuregroup->contain();
$measureGroups = $this->Measuregroup->find('all');
foreach ($measureGroups as $measureGroup) {
    $measures[$measureGroup['Measuregroup']['name']] = 
        $this->Report->Measure->find('list',
            array('conditions' => array(
                'Measure.measuregroup_id' => $measureGroup['Measuregroup']['id'])));
}
```

And in the view just this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Measure', array('label' => false, 'multiple' => 'checkbox'));
```